# "All Things Is/Are Ephemeral"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

> All Things *Is/Are* Ephemeral

I know that *are* is meant to be the verb connecting the two fragments together, but why...? (Gut instinct)

Answer (score 5):

The subject "All things" is plural, ergo the verb is plural.

The complement "ephemeral" is an adjective, and so does not inflect for number in English anyway; but even if it were a singular noun, as "All things are a nuisance", "are" would still agree with "all things".

Answer (score 1):

Because the word "things" is plural.  This is the phenomenon known as *case agreement*, in its *grammatical number* form.