# Agreement in "[Singular Noun] Is/Are [Plural Noun]"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, be, predicative-complements

1. My fish's native habitat is rice fields.
2. My fish's native habitat are rice fields.

Which one is correct? I'm pretty sure it's the first, since 'is' modifies 'habitat,' but it still sounds weird...

Comment: Just to be picky about terminology, *is* agrees with *habitat*.

Comment: Wait, do certain fish actually live in rice fields?! :)

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17588/all-things-is-are-ephemeral/17590#17590

Comment: @Jimi, Yep. http://www.petfish.net/kb/entry/339/.  Got one the other day and naturally follows lots of research.

Comment: I would probably say "My fish's native habitat is in rice fields." But I prefer an earlier answer: "Rice fields are …"

Comment: See also [Agreement with compound subjects joined by and](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and/117351#117351) for cases where singular override may be given to plural-form subjects considered as non-plural entities (eg bacon and eggs is on the menu) ('notional agreement').

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It may sound weird, but it is still correct. Singular nouns take singular verbs. In this case, the singular noun is *habitat*. Thus, *is* is the correct form of the verb *to be* in this case.

> My fish's native habitat *is* rice fields.

To make it sound more natural, you could reverse the order thus:

> Rice fields *are* my fish's native habitat.

Comment: Right, the second version would be natural. Note that adding a bit more detail with an article also solves the problem: "My fish's native habitat is the rice fields of Viet Nam."

Comment: It sounds weirder still when you use a first-person pronoun as the predicate nominative and modify a singular subject with a prepositional phrase ending in a plural: `The oldest of my siblings is I.`  Or perhaps `A family of happy people is we.`  Actually, I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: @JCooper For some reason those aren't so weird sounding to me.  I guess it has to do with a couple years of grammar intense German.  It's also easier because those sentences can be reversed and are clearly correct, and we can also get into Yoda-speak: The oldest of my siblings, I am.

Comment: Does it mean that when using is/are, it is simply the first subject that defines the number? (Or is the second "subject" not a subject, but an object?)

Comment: @arik-so: Indeed, it is the subject that determines the verb form you use. It does not matter whether the object is singular or plural.

Comment: Would "Rice fields **is** my fish's native habitat" incorrect, if I want to consider "rice fields" not as a plural subject but as a singular unit? @JimiOke

Answer (score 4):

Please advise, but [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/verbs-sandwiched-between-singular-and-plural-nouns) opines that the problem here is 'false attraction to a predicate noun'. I excerpt the fundaments:

> Although this problem may seem complicated, it’s really not. It’s as simple as this: the verb agrees with the subject (2)<sup>**1**</sup>, not the predicate noun. - See more at: [Verbs sandwiched between singular and plural nouns - Quick & Dirty Tips](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/verbs-sandwiched-between-singular-and-plural-nouns#sthash.y0KLwgtk.dpuf)
>
> Dorothy, don’t pay attention to the man behind the curtain, meaning don’t be distracted by the predicate noun. One grammar source calls this problem “false attraction to a predicate noun” (3). - See more at [Quick & Dirty Tips](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/verbs-sandwiched-between-singular-and-plural-nouns#sthash.y0KLwgtk.dpuf)

<sup>**1**. The (2) and (3) refer to external references on p 2 of 2 of Grammar Girl's article.</sup>