# Is "nothing but birds and a few insects" singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement, prepositional-phrases

> Nothing but birds and a few insects [was/were] to be seen.

In that sentence, should the verb agree with "nothing" or with "birds and a few insects"?

Comment: [Nothing but trees **were** to be seen](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nothing+but+trees+were%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: @Luis This is a very interesting question, and I can find examples from various corpora supporting both options. However, what I have not been able to do is figure out why one is one and not the other. I’ll post more come the morrow.

Comment: @Luis I’ve rewritten my answer from scratch based on my investigations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Is *nothing* singular or plural?

All by itself, **nothing is** clearer than the fact that *nothing* is singular.

However, the original question did **not** use *nothing* “all by itself”, and that is where things get sticky.

The question asks which of these two versions should be used:

> 1. Nothing but birds and a few insects **was** to be seen.
> 2. Nothing but birds and a few insects **were** to be seen.

This turns out to be a very interesting question indeed.  It depends on how you read that.  It could be read in either of these ways:

> 1. Nothing (apart from birds and a few insects) **was** to be seen.
> 2. Only birds and a few insects **were** to be seen.

Since native speakers vary in which of those two readings makes more sense to them or sounds better to them, you should choose whichever you feel more comfortable with.

---

## *Details, Details, Details*

After reading through grammars and examining various corpora for actual 
examples of how things like *nothing but <NOUN-PHRASE>* wind up being
used in subject position and what sort of concord they admit or allow, I have come to the conclusion that **different native speakers make different choices for this particular situation.**

Specifically, both of these types of examples can be readily found:

- <NEGATIVE-PRONOUN> but <PLURAL-NOUN-PHRASE> <VERB-SINGULAR>
- <NEGATIVE-PRONOUN> but <PLURAL-NOUN-PHRASE> <VERB-PLURAL>

Because both versions can be generated by native speakers, it is hard to say that one is “right” and another “wrong”.  In fact, what sounds perfectly fine to one speaker may sound completely off to another.

Below I show why and how this is.

---

### Are negative indefinite pronouns singular or plural?

Short answer: *yes*.  Or *either*.  Or *both*.  Or well really, **it just depends.**

Long answer follows.

---

The word *nothing* is a ***negative indefinite pronoun***.  The full list of these is

- none
- no one
- nobody
- nothing
- neither

Negative pronouns in English can vary in countability and number depending on how they are used. For example, *none* can be used both as non-count or count.

This is clearest when there is a
***postmodifying prepositional phrase*** to signal whether we’re dealing with
a count noun or a mass noun.

- None of the **butter is** left.
- None of my **friends are** coming.

This is similar to how premodifying prepositional phrases can work:

- A lot of the **butter is** left.
- A lot of my **friends are** coming.

The logical head of the noun phrase in these is **not** the same as its
grammatical head, in that these pre- and post-modifiers act like
determiners or adjectives, which means that they do not affect
subject–verb agreement.

One way to look at it is that *none of the* and *a lot of the* do not count for agreement purposes.  For some people, it turns out that *nothing but* has the same property.  But for others, it does not.

This is easy to see if we replace *none of the* with the negative
determiner *no*:

- No **butter is** left.
- No **friends are** coming.

We can do the same illustration with *a lot of*, but now we need
to choose *much* for non-count and *many* for count versions:

- Much **butter is** left.
- Many **friends are** coming.

The predeterminer *all (of)* works the same way:

- All of the **butter is** left.
- All the **butter is** left.
- All of my **friends are** coming.
- All my **friends are** coming.

In all these cases, clearly it is *butter* and *friends* which are the
logical heads of their respective noun phrases, and when that noun phrase acts as the subject of a finite clause, it is the logical head of that noun phrase that controls numeric agreement with the verb.

When the noun phrase has a *but* in it, it can be used as a conjunction or as a preposition.  As a coordinating conjunction, it is the second of a *not (only/just) . . . but (also/rather)* pair.

- Not only Jim's mother but also Jim himself **are** attending.
- Not only Jim's mother but he himself **are** attending.

Sometimes this acts disjunctively and so
can result in a singular verb:

- Not Jim's mother but rather Jim himself **is** attending.
- Not Jim's mother but he himself **is** attending.
- Not my mother but rather I myself **am** attending.
- Not my mother but I myself **am** attending.
- It is not not my mother but I myself who **am** attending.

At other times, it acts conjunctively and so requires a
plural verb:

- Not only Jim's mother but also Jim himself **are** attending.
- Not only Jim's mother but also he himself **are** attending.
- Not only my mother but also I myself **are** both attending.

Notice how any personal pronouns involved stay in subject case when
they are part of the subject.  It would be ungrammatical to
put them in oblique case when they act as the subject:

- Not Jim's mother but ***him is** attending.
- Not my mother but ***me am** attending.
- Not only Jim's mother but also ***him are** attending.
- Not only my mother but also ***me are** both attending.

---

## *Nothing but birds*

Now let’s look at the original problem to be solved:

> Nothing but birds and a few insects **was/were** to be seen.

Here *but* is acting **not** as a conjunction but as a preposition meaning
*except (for)*.  This is not a compound subject at all; instead it is a noun
phrase with a postmodifying prepositional phrase.  That means it works like
*none of the* and so can be **either** singular **or** plural.

- None of the birds **were** visible.
- None of the water **was** visible.

That seems to lead to the conclusion that the original sentence's
verb should be in the plural, since its logical head is plural:

> Nothing but birds and a few insects **were** to be seen.

Simple enough answer, but is it the right one?

No.  It is not **the** right answer; it is **a** right answer.  Others exist, as shall be demonstrated below.

---

### Corpus Examples

However, that is not the conclusion universally reached by native
speakers.  Some make the other choice for the same situation.  And there seem to be situations were it really cannot be plural.

For example, here you cannot seem to get away with using a plural verb:

- Nothing but my own thoughts **was** real to me.

Perhaps that is why actual citations in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) and Google Books show a
variety of choices here for the model of:

- <NEGATIVE-PRONOUN> but <PLURAL-NOUN-PHRASE> <VERB-SG/PL>

One COCA example uses a singular verb here:

- Maybe Pearl was Hiroshima. **Nothing but debating points is** to be gained by arguing such things. (PBS Newshour, 1991)

But other COCA examples use a plural verb instead:

- . . . it was almost impossible for Darryl to distinguish the members of the surgical team; **nothing but their eyes were** visible. (Analog Magazine, 2012)
- . . . so intently was she focused that she screened out a conversation that ended abruptly when **nothing but the crusts were left** on her plate.  (African-American Review, 2005)
- . . . my friends, your expense! You do the work of the world yet **nothing but crumbs come** your way!" (Southwest Review, 1996)

Google Books also has examples using singular verbs in this situation:

- By this irruption, however, **nothing but the suburbs was** yet gained: the entrance into the town was still more difficult. . . .
- Tradition, as already mentioned, placed Seming, a son of Odin, on the throne of that country, and from him descended a race of pontiff-kings of whom **nothing but their names is** recorded.
- At best, **nothing but their names is known;** for who among the multitude of men, who hear or who utter their names really knows anything about their lives or their deeds, or attaches to those names any definite idea?

And it isn’t just for *nothing*, either; *no one* can do the same thing.
If anything, *no one* is more resistant to being cast into the plural than
*nothing* is.  But not perfectly so.

Here is a COCA example using a singular verb even though the *you* part would take a plural one:

- **No one but you has** to notice, in order for it to screw up your world. (Mandala, 2006)

That contrasts with another COCA example where the writer has gone exactly the other way and chosen a plural verb after *no one but you*:

- She said **no one but you were** fit to direct her.

### This proves that native speakers make different choices for these situations!

But it gets stranger still. It’s not just the verb number that varies: even the pronoun case does.
COCA has curious examples of *no one but*  where the
pronoun is in subject case not oblique case.

- . . . to us; it required all the subtle tact of which I am capable. **No one but I could have** done it. No one but I would have done (Lion in Valley, 2008)
- . . . In a low, weary voice that **no one but I could hear**, he muttered: " Enjoy it, kid (American Heritage, 2000)
- . . . hand into his jeans pocket, something he did reflexively when he was nervous. **No one but she** knew that he was probably fingering the silver worry beads she'd (Pink Jinx, 2006)

That’s strange, because just between you and me, one would think it should be oblique case.

And indeed, often it is:

- . . . discussing themselves and their world in such a way that **no one but them could have** known. (Fantasy & Science Fiction, 1998)
- . . . Silence in the vehicle surrounded him. **No one but him was** laughing. He could feel the vehicle slowing down. (Forbidden, 2005)
- . . . rude gesture and half ran to lose himself in the crowd. **No one but me was** watching. (In Shadow Oak, 1991)

Google Books:

- The fact remains that she's gone and **no one but me remembers** her.
- striving for some transmutation **no one but them understands**.
- Mr. Paling: Is it not a fact that by the terms of reference Europeans should be in a privileged position, and that now, owing to the right  hon. gentleman's interpretation, **no one but Europeans has** any right to land at all ?
- You're in New York City. In a part of Central Park that **no one but us knows exists**. . . .
- Absorption of more work leads to the demand for even more, because **no one but us really knows** what librarians do, why it is important, and how much of it we can accomplish.
- Luckily we only had to shorten our trip by a day, but we did miss the first two days of classes . . . which **no one, but us, was** concerned about.

Yet other examples show it with a plural verb:

- **No one but Europeans were** allowed to live on the island.
- **No one but Americans visit** this famous spot; so say Englishmen.
- The Secret Service had closed off the estate, and **no one but police were** allowed in, and **no one except police — including the party guests — were** allowed to leave.

---

## In Conclusion

I have shown that both possible answers to the sort of puzzle posed by the original question do occur in actual text by native speakers.

After reading hundreds of examples, my **general sense** is that there are more situations where plural concord gets applied here than where singular does.

Additionally, many of the examples with singular concord occur in older or more formal texts.  But some are not.  It really just depends.

Beyond just conflicting subject–verb agreement, real-world examples demonstrate that not all native speakers agree about the case of the object of the preposition *but* when used in subject position.

This surprised me.

My tentative hypothesis is that they are construing *but* to be acting as a conjunction there instead of as a preposition.  That would justify leaving the pronoun in subject case instead of switching to oblique case.

Then again, it might also be simple hypercorrection.  Hard to say for sure.

Comment: @tchrist   I have a doubt about one of your examples:  "It is not not my mother but I myself who am attending."   Could I say "....but I myself who is attending." ?   or, to use another frase, "It's me("I" for the purists) who is supposed to do that."

Comment: @Luis You probably could do so without anybody much batting an eye.

Comment: @tchrist But not in an essay, I suppose ?

Comment: @Luis That probably deserves its own question, and quite probably has already been asked.  *I’m the person who is going to finish the job* and even *Little old me is going to finish the job* are probably both a lot more common than *It is I who am going to finish the job.*  Just use *will* instead of *am going*. :)

Comment: As one of the people who use subject case after _but_, I can say that I at least think of _but_ more as a conjunction than as a preposition. As such, the subject becomes whatever comes after _but_ and agrees with that “Nobody but I am going to tell you this”, for example). Switching to an unambiguous preposition, _except_, I also switch to oblique case and no agreement with the ‘second subject’: “Nobody except me is going to tell you this”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Great example, nice and short. Collocations in COCA for ***nobody but <PERS-PRONOUN> <VERB>*** are all over the map. These fragments show the issue: *Nobody but Britany and I knew.
nobody but me has the fight;
So nobody but me has stayed;
Nobody but us knows what's going to happen;
where nobody but us ever goes;
Nobody but you was ever good to me;
nobody but he knows what anybody;
a void that nobody but him knows about;
to something nobody but her seemed to her;
arguing laws nobody but they cared about;
Nobody but the scientists were ever interested;
nobody but slaves were.*

Comment: @tchrist   "...a void that nobody but HIM knows about" and "laws nobody but THEY cared about..."  Should we use nominative pronouns or objective pronouns after "but"?  I was taught to use objetcive pronouns after a verb or a preposition.

Comment: @Luis Yes, Luis, isn’t that extremely peculiar!? As Janus remarked, people seem to be construing it to be acting as a conjunction there. Well, or maybe they just don’t know better. Notice his own example of *Nobody but I am going to tell you this*. For him at least there can be no question of “not knowing better” — actual speakers simply say different things there. I think it is the proximity of the pronoun to the verb that seems to trigger this, but I am anything but clear. Speaking of such, I wonder whether he’d say *Anybody but me is a better pick* and contrast it with his earlier example.

Comment: @tchrist I see.  Somehow I had missed his comment.

Comment: @tchrist: I've reversed my original downvote and deleted the comments. It's now a truly sterling answer far more comprehensive and lucid than anything I could have come up with, so it's just as well I wasn't around yesterday to waste my time trying.

Comment: tchrist, a typo here "situations were it really cannot be plural".  Just en passant, I've re-read your answer and it's just fantastic.

Comment: Just in case this grammatical fire is wanting further fuel... In my draft book I have this sentence, which might be even trickier than the original posed for this discussion: "Nothing besides the walls and floor has been there for more than two decades."

After reading the discussion above, I suspect I can use **have** or **has** after **floor** without being categorically "wrong".

Note that **walls** is plural and **floor** is singular, just to add to the complexity of the problem.

I'm going with **has**.

Answer (score 1):

Subjects cannot be contained within prepositional phrases.  "but birds and a few insects" is a prepositional phrase.  "Nothing" is the subject.  "was" is the proper verb.  There is no argument here.

Comment: Technically, that's probably correct. Idiomatically/colloquially, I doubt that anyone would phrase it that way; I think most of us would treat "nothing but" as an emphasis modifier on "birds and a few insects".

Comment: @keshlam Not even sure what it would mean for a choice that is never used to be "technically" correct...?!?

Comment: As tchrist's answer shows, there is absolutely an argument here. Very much so.