# Singular or plural verb after ‘no’?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

- No errors or exceptions is found in the logs.
- No errors or exceptions
  are found in the logs.

Comment: If you ignore the _no_, and just look at _errorS_ or _exceptionS_, would you expect a singular or a plural? I think you might enjoy a look at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yes, but with the 'No' included, why should we describe it as a plural. No means nothing. How can nothing be plural ?

Comment: You can look at it two ways - either that the 'no' is a negation of the plural phrase : 'no (errors are found)' or that singular literally means one (i.e. therefore not any other number, including zero).

Comment: How can nothing be _singular_? Nothing is _neither_ singular nor plural, semantically. But grammatically, it's plural. If you have no problem using _errors_ in the plural, why is a plural verb a problem? If you would have proposed _no error or exception is found_, I would have understood your question better. As it is, you use plural nouns, and I don't understand why you would have a problem using a plural verb with a plural noun.

Comment: @oerkelens "But grammatically, it's plural" is what the Q is all about. There could be a previous post on this. Else [ell.se] can help.

Comment: @Kris: if that is what the Q is about, why does the Q not extend to the nouns? If the question is really about grammatical number due to _no_, it should have been asked with _singular_ _error or exception_. Obviously, when writing _errorS_, the grammatical number has been decided upon already, and is _no longer a question_.

Comment: Related: [first answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/181954/8019)

Comment: I have asked the mods to migrate this question to ELL. It's not a bad question, but it would be greatly improved if Ajay edited their comment: "Yes, but with the 'No' included, why should we describe it as a plural. No means nothing. How can nothing be plural ?" in the body text as it helps users to understand where the confusion has arisen. Good luck!

Comment: See the answers and comments on the linked question. Specifically, "Plural doesn't mean 'more than one'. It means 'any number other than one'. 1.0001 is plural. 0.99999 is plural. 0 is plural. -1 is plural. Only 1 is singular. The nature of singularity is being single, isn't it? Everything else is plural."

Answer (score 22):

You can use either singular or plural, but you must be consistent. If the nouns are plural, the verb must be plural as well.

> No error or exception is found in the logs.
>   <s>No errors or exceptions is found in the logs.</s>
>   No errors or exceptions are found in the logs.

Since it is possible to have multiple errors or exceptions, the plural form is the standard one — see [There are no comments /  There is no comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/there-are-no-comments-there-is-no-comment). However, given that the emphasis is on the absence of bad things, rather than on a count, [using the singular is also possible](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+*+was+found%2Cno+*+were+found&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cno%20%2A%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bno%20one%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20place%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20difference%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20evidence%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20man%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20difficulty%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20bottom%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20fault%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20correlation%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20relationship%20was%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cno%20%2A%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bno%20differences%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20fossils%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20changes%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20bones%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20traces%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20means%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20lesions%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20papers%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20nests%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bno%20eggs%20were%20found%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: +1 And [no man is an island](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~johnston/poetry/island.html).

Comment: And "No mans are islands" :)

Answer (score 3):

"no" does not mean nothing. You can use "no" as an adjective before a noun in singular or plural: no man, no woman, no thing - no children, no things. And the question whether a noun is regarded as singular or plural depends on the noun and not on "no".

Comment: Right. Please try to substantiate by citing from reliable sources. You seem to have not noticed the noun's number in the example sentences.