# "First part are [plural]", or "first part is [plural]"?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [[Singular] Is/Are [Plural]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/singular-is-are-plural)

I'm currently writing my master thesis on Bitcoin and I'm not sure which version of this sentence is correct:

"The first most important part of the Bitcoin infrastructure **are** all applications that communicate with the Network."

"The first most important part of the Bitcoin infrastructure **is** all applications that communicate with the Network."

Or perhaps both of them are wrong?

EDIT:

Finished sentences.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to see the entire sentence, but the head word of the subject of the sentence, *part*, is singular, so, other things being equal, you need the verb to agree with it, so it has to be *is*. However, the sentence might be clearer as:

> Those applications that communicate with the Network form the most
>   important part of Bitcoin’s infrastructure.