# Use of the singular or plural "is" or "are" in ambiguous situations

Tags: verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [[Singular] Is/Are [Plural]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/singular-is-are-plural)

In this sentence:

> The only exception are questions that are narrow enough that they can
>   be reasonably answered definitively with one or two possible
>   solutions.

Should it be "The only exception is" because "exception" is singular, or "The only exception are" because "questions" is plural?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default is that the verb agrees in number with its subject, so *The only exception is . . .*
If that sounds awkward, you can write *The only exceptions are . . .* , which is probably preferable anyway, given that *questions* is plural.

Comment: Or OP could sidestep the verb agreement issue by using, for example, *"the only exception **being** questions that are..."* He's probably need to terminate the preceding sentence with a semicolon to make it flow nicely though.