# Plural vs singular noun

Tags: nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [[Singular] Is/Are [Plural]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/singular-is-are-plural)

Is the following sentence correct?

> This report’s intended audience is the students of the University of Canada.

Can I use the verb "is" with a plural noun as the subject complement?

Comment: Yes. It also works the other way round: "The students ... are this report's intended audience."  Some people may be uncomfortable with it, but an *audience* is inherently both singular and plural.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't feel at all comfortable with *"**an** audience **are** inherently both singular and plural"*, but I have no such problem with *"**the** audience **are** inherently [flexible]"* (so it all depends which audience(s) we're talking about - **an indefinite** one, or **the definite** ones! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers A very nice point. What about *"Someday he will find himself before an audience who are not receptive to his extreme views"*?

Comment: @StoneyB: lol - Even "nicer" point! That particular audience would presumably have to be *the one **which is*** singular! Pluralistically speaking, I mean - there's nothing else particularly odd/unique/singular about them/it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Well, after word gets around he might encounter many such audiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the short answer is yes. *Is* refers to *audience* not students, which can be both plural and singular.