# "Favorite fruits are grapes" or "favorite fruit is grapes"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I think I understood the general idea of *fruits* vs *fruit*, but what about the situation where you're saying: "My favorite fruits are grape"?

This made me cringe when I saw it in an English course booklet. Would I be correct to assume that, in this case, we would say: "My favorite fruit is grapes"? The reason being that my favorite fruit *is*. But also, *grapes* is considered one group or type of fruit here, therefore fruit = is grapes.

Did I explain this correctly? Is this the right assumption? I think that "favorite fruits are..." would be used if you're going to say "grapes and apples".

Comment: What is meant here is that I like all varieties of grapes. Plural is fine.

Comment: _Favorite fruit_ is a predicate noun phrase and therefore singular. That's the fixed phrase. As far as the grammar is concerned, it doesn't matter whether you eat your favorite fruit in little pieces or in one big bite.

Comment: [This topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/444208/my-favorite-food-is-apples-is-it-ok?noredirect=1&lq=1) addresses the same question, with an opposite answer to the one given here.

Comment: [See also here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/agreement-in-singular-noun-is-are-plural-noun) for Y is/are Xs.

Answer (score 3):

"My favorite fruit is grapes." As you're talking about one (kind of) FRUIT and it's singular. Just like other things, you don't say "My favorite subjects are science" what you say is "My favorite subject is Science"