# My favorite food is apples. Is it ok?

Tags: verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, food

My favorite food is apples.
Or my favorite food are apples.

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/36/2f/53/362f53906df8f0ecbb32a15d4b2e10af.jpg

Comment: Ooh,  you changed it. Now it's about verb agreement. So you're no longer interested whether the noun (apple) should be singular or plural? Please clarify. And please fix the spelling of "favorite"(US spelling)

Comment: Of course it's okay! Everyone has a favorite food :) (Disclaimer, because this is the Internet: this is a joke.)

Comment: My favorite is plural noun  is it ok?

Comment: This question is asking how 'my favorite X' should handle an uncountable category (subject) but a countable answer (object). 'I like apple(s)' is a rephrase of this question; it's the correct answer as far as *getting around* the question; **but isn't a *duplicate* of it**.

Comment: For one treatment of an answer at the ELL site, [see the first part of the answer here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/169598/52137).

Comment: The content, if not the title, of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132837/favorite-fruits-are-grapes-or-favorite-fruit-is-grapes) covers this topic, with an opposite answer to what we have here.

Comment: Never paid due attention to +1 Though, my favorite is apple sounds comfortable, a non native speaker to me.

Answer (score -1):

Food is singular; foods is plural. So, "My favorite food is apple, and my favorite foods are apples and oranges."

Comment: Or even "My favorite food is apples and oranges", if it's taken to mean a literal dish of apple and orange slices, for example.