# Subject/Complement Agreement. How to describe problem with "The thing is/are the objects."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, agreement

In my [ell answer, version 32](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/29170/32), I provided the following, problematic,  wording (especially ***bold italic***), and I need help to better understand this issue so I can fix my answer:<sup>1</sup>

> > The thing is the books. (Reduced form of Sentence 2.a)
>
> ***Fundamentally, Sentence 2.a (the so-called "correct" answer), is grammatically defective. Recall there is another grammatical rule: the subject and subject's complement should match in number.***

A clarification is needed here. I am **not** suggesting here, in ***this*** EL&U question, that there is any such singular grammatical rule as indicated in the quote above.  The quote continues as follows:

> The reduced sentence makes the disagreement between the subject's and complement's plurality obvious. What is one to do? Language is linear and we know "The thing is X" is better than "The thing are X", so we go with the former, which is the subject-verb agreement rule. But what is "the books" then? It must be thought of as a collective noun, even if it doesn't look or feel like one. Forcing something to be a collective noun is related to the idea of notional agreement.

Others noted that ***grammatically defective*** is too strongly worded.  There is no such "grammatical rule" for subject/complement agreement.  Please help me understand/improve upon my line of thought here.  I'm stating that Sentence 2.1 presents a fundamental "conflict" or "error" (however one might define *error*) at some level (morphological, syntax, grammatical, semantic):

> The thing is the books.  (Or, "The thing is the objects.")

Based on the "obvious" morphosyntactic plurality conflict, the above sentence feels so wrong that I think many native speakers would think it "simply" grammatically incorrect. However, @F.E. gives counter examples:

> And here are some more grammatical examples, where the number of subject and predicative complement don't agree: "They were a problem to us all", "That so-called work of art is simply four pieces of driftwood glued together" (CGEL, page 254-5). As CGEL says: "What is required is semantic compatibility, not syntactic agreement . . .". There are more examples on page 512: "The only thing we need now is some new curtains", "The major asset of the team is its world-class opening bowlers", "Our neighbors are a nuisance", "This gadget is five different tools in one".

I think all the examples given above can be explained as notional agreement.

**Question 1:** If we explain this phenomena in terms of notional vs syntactic agreement, where does "grammatically correct/incorrect" fit in?

**Question 2:** Can a simple sentence such as *"The thing is the objects."* be grammatically incorrect while more complex sentences such as *"The thing is four pieces of driftwood glued together."* be grammatically correct?  (The answer, in my mind, must be no; this is my conundrum.)

**Question 3:** Would it be better to say that Sentence 2.a has a low level of (linguistic) [grammaticality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticality)?

**Question 4:** How about a low level of [gradient well-formedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_well-formedness) and that it's semantically difficult to be (linguistically) [acceptable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptability_(linguistics))?

**Question 5:** Do we simply draw a hard line and say *"The thing is the objects."* is 100% grammatically correct?  I didn't particularly *like* this option based on intuitive notions of "grammatically correct".

---

<sup>1. Please help me and be kind; I'm trying to improve my understanding. I'm looking for cool, objective advice on how to look at this.</sup>

<sup>I numbered my questions so they can be easily referenced, if desired.  My preference is the final answer would sufficiently answer all the questions, but of course that can be done explicitly or implicitly.</sup>

Comment: "It's us" is virtually universally accepted, so the 'rule' is a pseudorule at best.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was just about to make the same point, but with “It is them” as the example. Or “They are it”, for that matter. But then obviously both those examples use abstract- or dummy-like _it_; Semantic compatibility is quite easy to attain with pronouns that may be used in very abstract manners. “That car is just spare parts” is a ‘purer’ example, but there seem to be some fairly stringent underlying rules that determine how semantic compatibility is ‘calculated’. Metonymy seems to play a role, too: “She’s (all) bones/thumbs” is fine, but “She’s swimmers” is not.

Comment: The only agreement rule is that finite verbs must agree with their subject.  Period.  There is no such thing as “subject–complement” agreement in English, be it grammatical or notional.  *The problem is the horses* is perfectly normal, standard, and correct in all possible ways, and therefore since your question is based on a false premise — that there is some sort of “problem” with that form — it can have no possible answer.

Comment: I agree completely with @tchrist in this. This is a zombie rule, with no purpose and no evidence; just some ignorant pedagogue laying down the law. As Geoff Pullum (who actually **did** write a grammar of English) puts it, anybody can publish any bullshit they please about English grammar, and somebody will believe them if they act sufficiently authoritative. Because Anglophone education teaches native speakers nothing at all about English; in fact, it's negative education, because native speakers enter school speaking English already, but leave doubting their ability to do so.

Comment: It is slightly off-topic for me to say so, but reading this question made me smile.  When I came here to ELU I had been thoroughly indoctrinated as a prescriptivist.  I wasn't even aware of the distinction between prescriptive and descriptive schools of thought.  Now, after a brief time, I find myself so in love with the descriptive paradigm, that I have zero interest in tackling a question like this today.  It's an odd reason to smile, I know.  But I'll take the opportunities as they arise. :) [Old me would have cringed at any sentence beginning with the word but.]

Comment: @CoolHandLouis There are uncountably many sentences whose grammar is impeccable but which make no sense whatsoever. Yours is merely one of them. Why you choose to represent a plural noun with a singular pronoun I have no earthly idea, but that’s your own fault.

Comment: I must say that so far, I'm very disappointed w/ the (jaded?) attitudes of what I thought would be stackexchangers trying to help another sincere stackexchanger.I expect more from you guys/gals. I stated in the question, *"There is no such 'grammatical rule' for subject/complement agreement."* I have great respect for the knowledge of the people who have commented so far.  But so far, only @JanusBahsJacquet has addressed this question with some level of insight ***beyond the obvious***. If helping me to draw proper lines between grammar/semantics/morphosyntax is a bad question I'll delete it.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: Look, there's no "phenomenon" to "explain". Sometimes predicate noun phrases are plural and sometimes their subjects are plural, but no guarantees either way, and all four possibilities exist. What's special about this one?

Comment: Janus wisely hedges in his com-ans: "... there seem to be some fairly stringent underlying rules that determine how semantic compatibility is ‘calculated’ / Metonymy seems to play a role, too". He doesn't attempt a complete answer; I'd say there's ample material involved to fuel a few doctorates. I'll add the observations that idioms often contradict logic (It's us, the thing is the neighbours, she's all thumbs ...) and that other 'mismatches' often occur and seem quite acceptable (A jury is twelve people who ...). As Janus says, not every pairing is considered acceptable: English is quirky.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for the points. So sentences starting as *"The thing..."* are often idiomatic, like *"The thing I want is the books"*  which is similar to *"What I want is the books"*. On the other hand, *"The thing is the books"* can lose the idiomatic flair and can be interpreted more literally, closer to the nonsensical sentence "The girl is the swimmers."  That does help me a bit. But as you say (and Janus intimates), there's much more that could be said about this phenomenon.

Comment: Ah, I was taking 'The thing is the books' at face value. I'd say that it is unacceptable to chop 'The only thing I want you to apply yourself to now is your books' or similar down to this level. I expected a context like _'Will you have enough money for your first year at uni?' _'Well – the thing is, the books.' If you don't like the frills, _'Pardon?' _'The thing is the books.'

Comment: +1 @EdwinAshworth, Yes!  I agree that was a fundamental mistake to reduce/chop the sentence so far. I'm definitively going to retract/fix that. But you also help me with your contribution of a plausible context for (comma included) *The thing is, the books* which is clear compared to the ambiguous (no comma included) *The thing is the books*.  Perhaps the more learn'ed here automatically interpret *The thing is the books* as having that comma since any other interpretation is nonsensical.  And yet, I was hesitant to use the comma in any of my writing or comments for fear of "the comma police".

Comment: If I remember correctly, the comma police here use various different law books. And John Lawler thinks that commas are off-topic (or should be). I've used a comma to mimic the sentence construction (after the comment clause) in 'The thing is, I may not be able to afford all the expensive books I'll need'. The repeat would probably be delivered without a pause, and the written form is clear from the first instance, so I'm quite happy to omit the comma in the repeat. The use of the comma to signal pauses in dialogue rather than just for clarifying particular structures is contentious, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Agreement in "\[Singular Noun\] Is/Are \[Plural Noun\]"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/agreement-in-singular-noun-is-are-plural-noun)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The thing is the books.

As the preponderance of comments suggests, an appropriate way to describe the grammar of this sentence, along with a host of others just like it, is: ***it is [aces](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ace&defid=286235)***:

> Exclamation that expresses something as being exceedingly good.
>   *Urbandictionary.com*

Divorcing the reduced construction from its larger context might give some native speakers pause, because the reduction eliminates contextual signals of the idiomatic usage:

> *[thing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thing)*
>
> noun
>
> 6 (the thing) informal Used to introduce or emphasize an important
>   point:
>
> *ODO*

One might argue that *the thing is the books* is inappropriate for a **formal** lecture or paper, but one cannot argue that it is *grammatically defective*. The reduced expression is correct, and in its original context, it doesn't sound the least bit strange:

> The only thing that I want you to hit right now is the books.

One might forgive an untrained writer for the erroneous *[proximity agreement](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/proximityagreement.htm)*, and even decipher the meaning of it in the full sentence:

> *The only thing that I want you to hit right now ?are? the books.

But it is, in fact, erroneous proximity agreement between the verb and the predicative complement, as the reduced construction reveals:

> *The thing ?are? the books.

It is one thing to forgive an error. It is quite another thing to teach an error, and the OP's rule may seem correct under cursory inspection, but it is spurious. Must the subject and subject complement match in number?

The only reason *the thing is the books* might sound strange is that our ears are more familiar with common predicative expressions of similar construction:

> - The girls are musicians. But not: The girls are musician.
> - The car is a clunker. But not: The car is [the] clunkers.
> - The actors are men. But not: The actors are man.

Even if the vast majority of predicative complements **happens** to match the number of the subject, there is no universal syntactical rule requiring it. Consider how simple it is to generate exceptions to this imaginary rule:

> - Taxes **are** the issue. ***Or*** The issue **is** taxes.
> - The prices **are** my concern. ***Or*** My concern **is** the prices.
> - The mosquitos **are** his problem. ***Or*** His problem **is** the mosquitos.
> - Her clothes **are** the point. ***Or*** The point **is** her clothes.
> - Flowers **are** today's subject. ***Or*** Today's subject **is** flowers.

In the five constructions above, mismatching the number of the subject and predicative complement works in both directions:

> *plural X* ***are*** *singular Y*
>   AND
>   *singular Y* ***is*** *plural X*.

The reason is quite simple: regardless of which is the subject, the predicative syntax cooperates with the semantics of the singular noun to put the plural noun in a single collective bucket. An idiomatic usage of *the thing* exerts the same collectivizing influence on *the books*:

> - The books **are** the thing. ***Or*** The thing **is** the books.

*The thing* is singular, and the writer has chosen to equate *the books* with *the thing*. Apparently, the writer intends the reader to recognize the collective nature that turns *the books* into *the thing*. Should the reader respect the intentions of the writer, or cast pseudo-grammatical insults at the writer?

---

Prescriptive grammarians presume to keep our language "manageable" by giving arbitrary orders to native speakers. Deep in their intuitive understanding of how English really works, native speakers know better, but tragically, they cave in to the intimidation of seventy-five-cent obfuscations like *morphosyntactic plurality conflict*. [People who can say such big words with presumptive authority probably know more than us, right?]

Since there is no *morphosyntactic plurality conflict* in the sentence, what is it that bothers the prescriptive grammarian? It ***is*** the ***words***, the *intelligent arrangement* of the words, ***and*** the intelligent speaker's refusal to fill the *erroneous prescription*. Please notice the previous sentence:

> It ***is*** the ***words*** [that bother the prescriptive grammarian].

We might call it a *[dummy-subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun)*, but *it* is singular, because the larger context invited *it* to match the interrogative *what is it*. The syntax of English ***requires*** the verb to match the singular subject with the singular form: *is*. After that, the predicative complement offers an intelligent answer to the question: *the words* bother the prescriptive grammarian. Again, notice how the larger context welcomes the plural **words**, because a long list of perfectly intelligent constructions irritates prescriptive grammarians.

The *coup de grâce* for the prescriptive grammarian's imaginary *morphosyntactic plurality conflict* is that the sentence answers the question with a compound complement in addition to a plural complement:

> It ***is*** the ***words***, the intelligent arrangement of the words, ***and*** the intelligent speaker's refusal to fill the erroneous prescription.

*[Semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics)* is about the meaning of words. *[Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax)* is about the intelligent arrangement of words in sentences. When native speakers understand they are not sick, they just refuse to fill the erroneous prescription. *The thing is the books* is not at all *grammatically defective*, and the prescriptive grammarian exposes his own ignorance of English grammar by asserting the imaginary defect.

---

> Question 1: If we explain this phenomena [sic] in terms of notional vs
>   syntactic agreement, where does "grammatically correct/incorrect" fit
>   in?

The premise of contradiction is flawed. From grammar.about.com, the definition of *[notional agreement](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/notionalagreementterm.htm)* is:

> Agreement (or concord) of verbs with their subjects and of pronouns
>   with their antecedent nouns on the basis of meaning rather than
>   grammatical form. Also known as *[synesis](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/synesisterm.htm)*.

The singular verb *is* agrees with the subject, so it is *[agreement](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/agreementerm.htm)*, not "notional agreement." Even if there were a universal syntactical rule requiring the agreement of the subject and the predicative complement, it would be a discrete rule with no hard and fast bearing on the agreement between subject and verb. Regardless, the predicative syntax operates with the semantics of the singular subject to collectivize the plural predicative complement.

---

> Question 2: Can a simple sentence such as "*The thing is the objects.*"
>   be grammatically incorrect while more complex sentences such as "The
>   thing is four pieces of driftwood glued together." be grammatically
>   correct? (The answer, in my mind, must be no; this is my conundrum.)

Although confused prescriptive grammarians might hope to salvage their sullied reputations, the simple sentence is just as correct as the more complex sentence, because in both situations, the predicative syntax operates with the semantics of the singular noun to collectivize the plural noun.

In the more complex sentence, the the semantics and syntax of the modifying phrase *glued together* reinforce the collectivization of the perfectly grammatical reduced expression: *The thing is four pieces of driftwood.* Please, notice that even this non-idiomatic use of *The thing* works quite well to break the imaginary rule about matching the number of subject and complement.

---

> Question 3: Would it be better to say that Sentence 2.a has a low
>   level of (linguistic) grammaticality?

Since the expression is perfectly grammatical, it might be better to say that the prescriptive grammarian making such a claim has a low level of insight into English grammar.

---

> Question 4: How about a low level of gradient well-formedness and that
>   it's semantically difficult to be (linguistically) acceptable?

Since the expression is well-formed and quite easy to understand, only a frustrated prescriptive grammarian refusing to abandon an imaginary rule would find it difficult to accept.

What is truly unacceptable is instructing students to break a real syntactic rule for the sake of applying a spurious rule. It would seem acceptable to lay out a **descriptive** rule for students: *The subject complement **normally** agrees with its subject.*

---

> Question 5: Do we simply draw a hard line and say "The thing is the
>   objects." is 100% grammatically correct? I didn't particularly like
>   this option based on intuitive notions of "grammatically correct".

Intuition informed by error is erroneous intuition. Native English-speaking Everyman has drawn an intelligent intelligible line, and most intelligent people are delighted to talk and write on Everyman's side of the line. What is it that bothers the prescriptive grammarian?

> *It is **semantics**, **syntax**, and the intelligent speaker's refusal to fill an **erroneous prescription***.

Comment: I can't make sense of lines 2-4 here. The plural form doesn't appear in the first few pages in your linked article, and 'It is aces' seems barely (if at all) idiomatic. A Google 3-gram for 'It is aces' flatlines. UD comments are not authoritative. Even if 'It is aces' _is_ a niche usage, it seems better interpreted as a niche / slang fixed phrase taking the singular rather than as having a true plural complement. There are far better, clearer examples.  I'll edit this out unless you can explain the relevance (or edit it out yourself).

Answer (score 0):

**The only agreement rule is that finite verbs must agree with their subject.** Period. There is no such thing as “subject–complement” agreement in English, be it grammatical or notional. The problem is the horses is perfectly normal, standard, and correct in all possible ways, and therefore since your question is based on a false premise – that there is some sort of “problem” with that form – it can have no possible answer.                                                                                                                                                             –tchrist♦

Comment: I'd add that some 'mismatches' (It's us / The problem is the people involved) sound far better than others (the one problem is the many different factors involved'; 'the jury was making a fool of itself'); synesis (the jury were ...) helps here.