# Is this correct pluralization? "it is these three.."

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> It is these three sentences that show why I am an expert orator

Suppose that there are three paragraphs above this line that each talk about one of the three sentences being referenced.

Should it be

> These three sentences are the ones that show why I am an expert orator?

If a mod feels this thread may be redundant given the one posted in the comments, you have my blessing to close it. If you think it isn't redundant enough, then that's fine as well.

Comment: Hugely related and probably a duplicate: [Subject-complement agreement](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187084/subject-complement-agreement-how-to-describe-problem-with-the-thing-is-the-obj).

Comment: Why do you think there's anything wrong here? What's your first language?

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrew_Leach, that thread is a great resource. tchrist my first language is English; but the lack of plural agreement between "is" and "three sentences" gave me some concern. Instinctively, one might expect "is" to be followed by an adjective or singular noun depending on the context.

Comment: Verbs agree with their subjects in English, not with their complements.

Comment: I don't think that I was ever taught that before. Good to know though

Comment: 'It is us' / 'It's us' // 'It's the Smiths' probably cause you no problems.

Comment: True enough Edwin, I just never realized what it was that I was doing, one could say.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subject/Complement Agreement. How to describe problem with "The thing is the objects."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187084/subject-complement-agreement-how-to-describe-problem-with-the-thing-is-the-obj)