# Question about parts of a sentence

Tags: phrases

I have a question about this sentence: "The tarsier's most remarkable feature, however, is it's enormous eyes, which, relative to body size, are the largest eyes of any mammal."

What part of the sentence is "of any mammal", specifically? Our textbook states that "the largest eyes of any mammal" is a noun phrase, but what part of the sentence is "of any mammal", specifically?

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence: "*The tarsier's most remarkable feature, however, is it's enormous eyes, which, relative to body size, are the largest eyes of any mammal.*" the words *of any mammal* constitute a prepositional phrase. The phrase contains  the possessive preposition *of* as the head and *any mammal* as its complement. The whole prepositional phrase is a post-modifier of the head of the noun phrase *eyes*.

---

Additional information:

Ash claims in his or her answer that the sentence is incorrect, and *is its eyes* should be replaced by *are its eyes*. It's not quite that clear-cut. There have been many discussions about this issue (copula agreement with the subject or with the complement?) on this site. Here for example:

- [Subject/Complement Agreement. How to describe problem with “The thing is the objects.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187084/subject-complement-agreement-how-to-describe-problem-with-the-thing-is-the-obj)

The following article is an in-depth analysis of the problem:

- [SUBJECT COMPLEMENT - VERB CONCORD IN ENGLISH](https://www.gla.ac.uk/schools/critical/aboutus/resources/stella/projects/glasgowreview/issue4-ardehali/)

One thing is indisputable however: it should be *its eyes* not *it's eyes*.

Answer (score -1):

The original sentence is incorrect. It should be

> "The tarsier's most remarkable feature, however, **ARE** it's enormous eyes..."

Also, I'm going to try explaining what the sentence means since I think that is the source of your confusion.

There are two statements mentioned here:

- The tarsier's most remarkable feature are it's enormous eyes.
- It's got the largest eyes, when compared to it's body size, among all mammals. That means the ratio of the size of the tarsier's eye to it's body is the largest, when compared to any mammal.

"of any mammal" here means "when compared to any other mammal".