# Can I say, “The alternative to it are private schools.”?

Tags: subjects

Is it possible to use this word order for the two subjects?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you explain it further?

Comment: Is the sentence grammatically correct?
I am confused about An alternative are instead of is...

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: "The alternative would be private schools" sounds better.

Comment: I also think that it is incorrect, but I have already seen it in forums and was interested whether it is possible to say it or not. Thank you very much!

Comment: "Alternative" is singular.  The verb should agree with the subject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subject/Complement Agreement. How to describe problem with "The thing is the objects."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187084/subject-complement-agreement-how-to-describe-problem-with-the-thing-is-the-obj)