# agreement of the subject complement with the subject

Tags: complements, agreement

A colleague of mine asked me, "Can we say 'My favorite food is hamburgers.'"

I said of course it is correct. But she said a native speaker says it is wrong. It should be "My favorite food is the hamburger."

I know there are some similar questions here answered before. in this post: [Subject/Complement Agreement. How to describe problem with "The thing is/are the objects."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187084/subject-complement-agreement-how-to-describe-problem-with-the-thing-is-the-obj)

> The only agreement rule is that finite verbs must agree with their
> subject. Period. There is no such thing as “subject–complement”
> agreement in English, be it grammatical or notional. The problem is
> the horses is perfectly normal, standard, and correct in all possible
> ways, and therefore since your question is based on a false premise —
> that there is some sort of “problem” with that form — it can have no
> possible answer. –  tchrist ♦
> Jul 25, 2014 at 17:18

[image]

It is what I think. I just want to see what you guys think here and now.

Comment: There is a somewhat weak and pedantic argument in favour of "My favourite food is the hamburger" but there is no argument for "My favourite food is the meatball" or "My favourite food is the chip (french fry if you're American)" since no one  is ever served with one chip and, very rarely if at all, with one meatball.

Comment: The number mismatches typically occur with ascriptive "be", where the construction is generally reversible.  But consider the grammaticality of  _?Hamburgers is my favourite food_.

Comment: If you want to use a generic noun phrase like _the hamburger_, of course you can, though it's rather strange to use a formal generic with an informal noun like _hamburger_. [Definite generics](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), like all generic noun phrases, have their own grammar.

Comment: I would say "My favorite food is hamburger", without an article. "The hamburger" refers to a specific hamburger, not the general category of all hamburgers.

Comment: Barmer, it is considered wrong to say "My favorite food is hamburger", because "hamburger" is a count noun.

Comment: BillJ, "Hamburgers is my favourite food" is wrong because the verb does not agree with the subject.

Comment: @LouisLiu It's also a category name. Please remember to use `@name` to send a notification to someone. And of course you have to spell their name correctly, but that's easy because it has auto-completion.

Comment: @tchrist Apparently the jury is out with regard to possible copular inversion. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English)]. 'A concern was the objections.' Here, CI-aficionados say the verb agrees with the fronted complement.