# Which of these sentences is correct and why? "My favorite food is/are hamburger(s)"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

1. My favorite food is hamburgers.
2. My favorite food are hamburgers.
3. My favorite food is hamburger.

As a native speaker, I know instinctively that number 1 is correct but I'm finding it difficult to summarize this for my students in an understandable way.

Comment: For me, only 3 is correct, for **food** is a **countable noun**, In this case it should take singular verb, because you are talking about a particular food.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subject/Complement Agreement. How to describe problem with "The thing is/are the objects."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187084/subject-complement-agreement-how-to-describe-problem-with-the-thing-is-are-the) 'Can we say "My favorite food is hamburgers"?' is actually queried at a [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/575390/agreement-of-the-subject-complement-with-the-subject).

Comment: See also [agreement of the _subject complement_ with the _subject_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/575390/agreement-of-the-subject-complement-with-the-subject).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple agreement rule* is that the number of the verb should correspond to the number of the grammatical subject. *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p499) states the rule as follows:

> In simple agreement, the verb agrees with a subject with the form of
> an NP (noun phrase) whose person-number classification derives from
> its head noun.

The head noun in this case is *food*, so sentence 1 (*My favorite food is hamburgers*) is the right choice.

Garner, in *American English Usage* (p778) in the section **False Attraction to Predicate Noun** notes the temptation use the plural verb in such contexts:

> Occasionally a writer incorrectly looks to the predicate rather than
> to the subject for the noun that will govern the verb. The "correct"
> way of phrasing the sentence is often awkward, so the writer is well
> advised to find another way of stating the idea.

One example of "false attraction" listed by Garner is:

> You can use live or artificial bait to catch these fish. My favourite
> **are** top-water plugs, plastic jigs and live green backs or shrimp.

---

* There are many occasions when the simple rule stated above is overridden. For example, *Ten dollars is a lot of money for a hamburger* or *My family eat fish every Friday*.

Answer (score 1):

**Food** here means 'type of food' so it takes a singular verb.

In British English, **hamburgers** refers only to the patties, so (1) would be the most natural. In American English **hamburger** can mean the minced (ground) meat from which burgers are made, so using it as a non-count noun as in (3) would be possible.

Comment: My favourite dessert is cake. Cakes.

Comment: "In British English, hamburgers refers only to the patties" or the **sandwiches**, although just "burger" might be more usual in both cases these days. Also, I have seen "hamburger and chips" used as a mass noun in UK English ("I like hamburger and chips"), but not "hamburger" alone. I wouldn't discount it entirely. But if you're talking about the sandwiches, "My favorite food is hamburgers" would be more usual, even in the US.