# "Beans is our only option" or "Beans are our only option"— which is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

This sentence is in the context of dinner.

> Beans is/are our only option

I'm confused as to whether "is" or "are" is necessary in this construct.

Comment: Relevant: [Agreement in "Singular Noun Is/Are Plural Noun"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766), [Pumpkin Noodles is a thing or are a thing?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283255)

Comment: ...........Are.

Comment: [*Baked Beans **is** a dish made from dried beans, which **have** been boiled to soften and cook them. The beans **are** then put into an oven-safe vessel, covered by a sauce...*](http://www.cooksinfo.com/baked-beans)

Answer (score 1):

Some nouns that end in 's' and resemble the plural forms are treated as singular. Eg: politics, mathematics, measles etc.
'Beans' (baked/fried/cooked beans) as an item of food/dish is considered singular.
But if the seed or pod of the bean is thought of individually, 'beans' can be plural of 'bean'.