# are or is after plural but prior to singular

Tags: grammaticality

Which sentence is correct in this case?

> 1. Class conflict and class exploitation **are** the prime moving force in history of mankind
> 2. Class conflict and class exploitation **is** the prime moving force in history of mankind?

Comment: This question is basically the reverse of [Agreement in “{Singular Noun} Is/Are {Plural Noun}”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766) As with that question, you are supposed to make the verb agree with the subject.

Comment: You could improve your English by avoiding "prior to" when "before" will work. Familiar, short, Anglo-Saxon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "are the prime moving forces (plural)...". Your subject is two things.
I would also say "the history" and "humankind" rather than "mankind". :)

Comment: I agree with Brenda about the grammar ("are" and "the prime") of the sentences.

Comment: Better still, “... in human history,”.  But the objection to “mankind” was worth making.