# Combining singular and plural

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, singular-subject-and-verb

I wanted to see if anyone can confirm the following sentence reads correct, with proper agreement:

"Now remember, your sales and marketing teams are the life force that keeps business flowing to you."

I believe this is correct because the nearest noun to the verb "keeps" is singular, but I wanted to make sure. I also believe it is okay to say "sales and marketing teams are the life force," turning these two groups into a singular noun, but again, I wanted to be absolutely sure. Combining singular and plural always seems a little uncertain to me. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: 1) sales-and-marketing team or teams OR 2) sales team or teams and marketing team or teams: which is it? But seriously, is there more than one of either?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Agreement in "\[Singular Noun\] Is/Are \[Plural Noun\]"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/agreement-in-singular-noun-is-are-plural-noun) {A and B are C} or {C is A and B} except in extreme circumstances. But also, yes: "Now remember, your sales and marketing teams are [the life force that keep**s** business flowing to you]."

Comment: The subject of _keeps_ is _the life force_; the _sales and marketing teams_ are not grammatically connected with _keeps_ in any way.