# "Is" followed by a plural noun

Tags: grammar

I just heard someone say "The noisiest thing outside is the birds". I understand the use of "is" being preceded by the singular "thing". But, the plural "birds" followed by "is", why is this correct? What is generally the rule here?

Comment: Not that the spoken has the strictness of the written word, but you could have *the thing is* or *the thing are*. I'd go with *is*.

Comment: @Yosef: *the thing are* is ungrammatical. Did you mean *the things are*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Agreement in "\[Singular Noun\] Is/Are \[Plural Noun\]"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/agreement-in-singular-noun-is-are-plural-noun) // In [NP₁] is/are [NP₂], the choice of verb form is **always** governed by NP₁ (the first noun phrase), whether it is considered the subject or the complement in a case of copular inversion. Easy so far. But NP₁ may look plural but be notionally singular ('Bacon and eggs is my favourite meal.')

Comment: @PeterShor "I'd go with is" is my way of saying there's no choice to make.

Comment: Then I'll post a comment: the only grammatical choices are *the noisiest thing is* or *the noisiest things are*. Since there's more than one thing, *things* is a little bit better.

Comment: Mismatches of number with specifying"be" where the subject is singular and the predicative plural are quite common. But with the ascriptive use of "be", mismatches most often have a plural subject in construction with a singular predicative, as in [_Our neighbours] are [a nuisance_]; [_The people who live there] are [a minority cult group_].